# Limits to ggplot legend element sizes

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to create a "colour" legend key that has a thick border independently of how thin it is in the corresponding geom_sf. This legend also has to have a specific size.

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

nc_mod <- nc %>% 
  mutate(H_IN_NAME = if_else(str_detect(NAME, "h"), TRUE, FALSE))

g_legends <- ggplot(nc_mod) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  geom_sf(aes(colour = H_IN_NAME), fill = NA, size = 0.2)


g_legends + theme(legend.key =
                    element_rect(size = 9))
```

The following image seems to reserve the space for a size 7, but it still sticks to the `geom` size for the actual colour.

[image]

```r
g_legends + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 7, fill = NA)))
```

Here I override the colour, but there seems to be a cap as the thickness of the line does not correspond to 7.

[image]

Are there any such "caps" or limits on the sizes of various legend elements and how are these determined?

Finally, when I add an overall size for the legend keys (whether before or after), the thickness of the border is ignored again.

```
g_legends + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 7))) +  
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.3, "cm"))
```

Any way of making the "colour" legend as in the second image or possibly a bit thicker *and* making the overall legend size smaller?

Thank you!